# How do I recover my database?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database

I exported my database to test whether it works. I then deleted the database and then it went to the "Trash" (I'm using Ubuntu). I then deleted it from "Trash" accidently.

Is there a way to recover my database?

Comment: I'm voting to close and move to http://superuser.com/ - it's about a deleted file in ubuntu. It makes little difference that it was a database.

Comment: I think you have to search for some file recovery tools. It depends on your file system: ext2, ext3 and so on.

Comment: How did you export your database?

Answer (score 2):

if you exported your database you can import it again, right? e.g. using [phpmyadmin](http://phpmyadmin.net)

Answer (score 1):

It's deleted permanently, the DB platform can do nothing for you, you might try a file recovery software, like [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (both work with Ubuntu), but it has a quite low success rate in these situations.